# Difference between "fuming" and "seething"

Tags: difference

The man was fuming/seething.

- Is there any difference between "fuming" and "seething" when used like this to describe someone expressing unexpressed anger?
- Which one of them describes best that it's unexpressed anger?
- Is one of them stronger in meaning than the other?
- Is one of them more American/British than the other?

Comment: _Fuming_ means _smoking (giving off smoke)_ and _seething_ means _boiling_. I don't think there is any difference in intensity when used as metaphors for anger, but _seething_ has more of an implication that the anger is unexpressed. This is from a British point of view. I'll leave it to Americans to say whether it's the same for them.

Comment: For what it's worth: two French hitchhikers to whom I gave a lift asked me politely whether I minded if they fumed!

Comment: 'Fuming' is something that UK right-wing newspaper headlines and stories claim that people do, e.g. because of e.g. 'Brussels', 'political correctness', 'red tape', etc.